# Is it possible to use limit to find collision between two subjects

Tags: limits

Let's say that in a game I have a subject $A$ placed at $(0, 5)$ and a subject $B$ placed at $(5, 0)$.
Accordingly, their distance is $5\sqrt{2}$. The subject $A$ will walk that distance at a constant velocity in a infinite loop. The subject $B$ will walk from $(5, 0)$ to $(0, 0)$ at the same velocity also in a infinite loop. Now, I don't know if it's true, but I believe that given they walk at the same velocity a different amount of distance ($5 \neq 5\sqrt{2}$), at some point they'll meet at $(5, 0)$. Can I prove that they'll meet? Is it possible to use limit to define when will they meet? Thanks.

Comment: You can't go the same velocity as someone else and cover more distance.  Can you clarify?

Comment: As you have it written now, unless A moved to B's initial position instantly (or B didn't move at all), I don't understand how they could ever meet at (5,0). A moves from (0, 5) to (5, 0) and B moves from (5, 0) to (0, 0) in the shortest straight line path, yes?

Comment: @Tyler yes. 
A moves 5√2. B moves 5. Before A reach B's initial position, B will already be comming back to it's start. Repeat that a right amount of time and they'll collide.

Comment: So, they move between their initial position and "final" position until they collide? That makes a lot more sense. You might want to put that in your question because it is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ will be at the point $(5,0)$ at times $t_A=(2n+1) 5 \sqrt{2}/v$ , $B$ at $t_B= m \, 5/v$, for $t_A=t_B$ we must have some integer $n,m$ such that $ (2 n+1) \sqrt{2} = m$. This cannot happen, because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Now, if you are willing to place some "tolerance" (they "almost" meet), it's true that as time increases you'd get better and better approximations (this would amount to get fractional approximations to the irrational number).

Comment: I understood the logic and the slope m easily. What I did not understand is why the slope for A is (2n + 1)?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something, if $t_1$ is the time that takes A  to travel from $(0,5)$ to $(5,0)$ (and viceversa), A arrives at the point at times $t_1$, $3 \times t_1$ $5 \times t_1$... Don't you agree?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to find out, given that I do have some tolerance, what is the limit of their collision? I mean, what would be the smallest distance possible between the two of them?